# Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>?'

Tags: swift, pointers

How do I cast a `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` to a `UnsafePointer<UInt8>?`? Like how in C it's like `(unsigned char*)VoidPointer`?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a raw pointer, you can `load` an object from an address within the memory, or you can *bind* the memory to derive a typed pointer to the same memory:

```
// buff is a CVImageBuffer
if let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buff) {
    // baseAddress is an UnsafeMutableRawPointer
    let addrptr = baseAddress.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) // *
    // addrptr is an UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>
    // ...
}
```